# Could you explain pointers and recursive structs

Tags: c++, c, recursion, struct, fsm

Could you explain what the pointers inside the structs mean? and how can recursive structure be useful? and could you please explain this code for me please? and how will it behave in the memory?
Here is my C code:

```
struct State { 
unsigned long Out; 
unsigned long Time; //ms 
const struct State *Next[4];};
```

Comment: There is nothing recursive about a structure containing a pointer to a structure of the same type. You can simply initialize this pointer to point to another structure of the same type, thus creating a linked-list of these structures.

Comment: `how can recursive structure be useful?:` Linked Lists, Trees, Graphs to name just a few.

Comment: @40two I didn'T understand you exactly

Comment: "recursive structures"s are use as building elements (i.e., nodes) of very popular data-structures like Linked-Lists, Trees and Graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `Next` can hold 4 pointers to objects of the same type (`struct State`) in read-only addresses (4 non modifiable references).

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct State { 
    unsigned long Out; 
    unsigned long Time; //ms 
    const struct State *Next[4];
}; 

void fn(struct State *data)
{
    /* data->Next[0]->Out = 1; error: assignment of member ‘Out’ in read-only object */
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%ld %ld\n", data->Next[i]->Out, data->Next[i]->Time);
        free((struct State *)data->Next[i]); /* cast to non const */
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct State data;
    struct State *next;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        next = malloc(sizeof(*next));
        next->Out = i;
        next->Time = i * 10;
        data.Next[i] = next;
    }
    fn(&data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer linked list example to understand the use of self referencing pointer.

```
const struct State *Next[4]; array of pointer.
```

So it can be used to pointer 4 self referencing address.

Find the linked list example in the below link

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/

Comment: Which list do you mean?

Comment: Linked List data structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pointer inside a structure means that pointer is called "Self referential Pointer". This pointer will point to the own structure.

```
struct State { 
unsigned long Out; 
unsigned long Time; //ms 
const struct State *Next[4]; // array of 4 self referential pointer.
};
```

These `*Next[4]` will point to the own structure. The Structure Which contains self referential pointer is called "Self referential structure".

A self referential structure is used to create data structures like linked lists, stacks, etc. A structure which contains a reference to itself. A common occurrence of this is in a structure which describes a node for a linked list. Each node needs a reference to the next node in the chain.

```
struct linked_list_node { 
int data; 
struct linked_list_node *next; // <- self reference 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "recursive `struct`". Containing a pointer-to-`State` is not the same as having a member `State`. The following code will cause an error:

```
// error!!
struct State {
    unsigned long IN;
    State someState;
};
```

Because the inner `State` member will have to have another `State` member within it, and so on, deep into the recursive rabbit hole.

Pointers to structs, however, can be useful. Consider an example implementation of linked list of `State` structs. Conceptually, it would look like this:

```
-----  ---> -----
| 9 |  |    | 5 |
-----  |    -----
| 5 |  |    | 4 |
-----  |    -----
|  -|---    |  -|----->
-----       -----
```

The second member there contains a pointer to another struct. Now, in C++, you have alternatives usually. In the case of linked lists, for example, you could do:

```
#include <list>

struct State {
    unsigned long IN,
    unsigned long OUT,
};

std::list<State> my_list;
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? Hopefully I'll be able to help.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nasser , a man has just answered me :) thank you for your efforts.